# assertTesting Function Sucess or Fail Test

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create an assertTesting function here that compare actual and expected values with strict equality (not typecasting).

As an example here's a success case:

```
function multiplyByTwo(n) {
  return n * 2;
}
var output = multiplyByTwo(2); // returns 4
assertTesting(output, 4, 'it doubles 2 to 4');
// console output:
// passed
```

Here's a failed one:

```
function multiplyByTwo(n) {
  return (n * 2) + 1; // an incorrect implementation
}
var output = multiplyByTwo(2); // returns 5
assertTesting(output, 4, 'it doubles 2 to 4');
// console output:
// FAILED [it doubles 2 to 4] Expected "4", but got "5"
```

Here's my codes so far:

```
var output;

function multiplyByTwo(n) {
  output = n * 2;
  return output;
}

function assertTesting (actual, expected, testName) {
  if(actual === ouput && expected === testName){
    return "SUCCESS" + [testname] + "Expected" + expected + "," "but got" + actual;
  }
}
```

Any idea how can I get the exact ouput I need? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this, I guess:

```
function assertEqual(actual, expected, testName) {
  if(actual !== expected){
    console.error( "FAIL [" + testname + "] Expected \"" + expected + ", \" but got \"" + actual + "\"");
  } else {
    console.info( "SUCCESS [" + testname + "]");
  }
}
```

Comment: how about the success? how it will go then?

Comment: What you want in success? `passed`?

Comment: How can I console.log the error then? It doesnt ouput.

Comment: How do you want to show it? This will be shown in developer console in your browser, for example